# "" Was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, set

I've pasted part of a script in below, where I am seeing problems with setting AJPPort. It is meant to pick up a setting further up in the script to use, which is a value of 8009. I want to have the option to change it if I want to, hence why I have this in the script. However at the moment it is giving me the error ="" was unexpected at this time. if NOT "!AJP!"="". I tried changing to if NOT "!AJP!"=="" but no luck. I've also got ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION set.

```
if "!InstallApache!"=="Y" (
    if "!HOLMESAuditMailbox!"=="" (
        set /p HOLMESAuditMailbox="Enter email address for alerting  : "
        echo HOLMESAuditMailbox=!HOLMESAuditMailbox!>> %SETTINGS_FILE%
)

if "!AJPHost!"=="" (
    set /p AJPHost="Enter Apache Proxy Destination Host    [localhost]: "
    if "!AJPHost!"=="" set AJPHost=localhost
    echo AJPHost=!AJPHost!>> %SETTINGS_FILE%
)

if "!AJPPort!"=="" (
if NOT "!AJP!"="" (
        AJPPort=!AJP!
    ) else (
        AJPPort=8009
    )
    set /p AJPPort="Enter Apache AJP Proxy Port    [!AJPPort!]: "
    echo AJPPort=!AJPPort!>> %SETTINGS_FILE%
)
```

)

Comment: To assign a variable you must use `SET`, so use `SET AJPPort=!AJP!` and `SET AJPPort=8009`

Answer (score 4):

change

```
if "!AJPPort!"=="" (
if NOT "!AJP!"="" (
```

to

```
if "!AJPPort!"=="" (
if NOT "!AJP!"=="" (
```